# How to retrieve text message from Android smartphone in Nodejs?

Tags: android, node.js

My Nodejs application requires retrieving text message from Android smartphone connected with USB cable. Is there a programmatic way to do it from Nodejs?

Comment: You can write android application listening over some port and replying to requests send by `nodeJs`

Comment: `Umer Farooq`, I am not familiar with the android application. is there an example I can follow? Thanks.

Comment: Pro tips: (1) there's no need to add thanks and appreciations to posts. We ask that authors use technical writing here, which is clear, succinct, and accessible to readers whose first language is not English. Thanks can be expressed in up votes and accept votes. (2) Please only use `code formatting` for code, and not for proper nouns (names of software packages or languages are not themselves code or IO).

Comment: Tanks for the tips. I thought thanks would not make technical post less technical and thanks is likely the first word a non EN speaker to learn. For `code formatting`, I use Ctrl K for proper format.  the `` is just same as bold font for emphasis.